# Automatic indentation for all prints of spc

Tags: t-sql, indentation

Frequently in procedures I use `raiserror('mystring',0,0) with nowait` for debugging purposes.

What I would like is the procedure itself to have a parameter, let's say `@indentation nvarchar(10)`, which will be applied(prefixed) to every such raiserror statement. The idea is that nested calls of procedures display results in a similar way we indent our code to clear things up, so one proc can call the other using a tab character as @indentation.

Currently, I just copy-paste the raiserror to always start with the parameter:

`raiserror('%smystring',0,0,@indentation) with nowait`

Is there a smarter way to do this? Or any close alternatives?

Comment: Instead of passing `@indentation`  around and needing to add it as a a param to each proc could maybe calculate it with `@@NESTLEVEL` and `REPLICATE`

Comment: Well, my main focus was to avoid the individual statements being cumbersome, as there are tens of them - a one-off work of using a parameter isn't as bad.

Comment: I Think @MartinSmith meant that you could create an sp or function that would not need any indentation parameter, it could use the current `@@NESTLEVEL` to determine how much to indent by, use `REPLICATE` to create the indentation spaces text, then append the error text. That way you would would only ever have to call `myIndentRaiseError('mystring', 0 0)`